# Javascript Modify Passed in Function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, edit

Is it possible to modify a function that is passed in as a param.

For example let's say I have this function

```
function masterFunction(func){
    func();
}
```

So I have a master function that calls the function that is passed in.

So I call my masterfunction by passing in my "current function" if you will

```
masterFunction(function(data){
    var variable = grabsValueFrom(data);
    if(variable && variable['status']){
        console.log('go');
    }
});
```

So this is what I pretty much have and working. However I'm now going to implement a change to my "grabsValueFrom" function, it will now have an index called "error" if there is an error.

So I can go to EVERY file and find my code and implement the new error index (hundreds of files) OR if I can edit the function inside "masterFunction" I can make the change once, ei

```
function masterFunction(func){
    //somehow add this to func():
    if(typeof variable.error != 'undefined'){
        console.log('got an error');
    }
    //now that it is added let's call our function
    func();
}
```

I understand this won't work but this is the best way I can explain what I *want* to do considering everything I google is about editing variable parameters, not necessarily the function being passed in itself.

Comment: You could nest a callback function as a param to the func param you're currently passing into masterFunction() - would that work? Or you could have masterFunction() call a static function (eg: "func2()") that can be dynamically changed to have it do what you want func to do when it's done

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the passed in function in another function.

```
function masterFunction(func) {
  var wrapperFunc = function (data) {
    if (typeof variable.error != 'undefined') {
      console.log('got an error');
      return;
    }
    return func(data);
  };
  wrapperFunc();
}
```

We don't really have a ton of context here so I'm not sure if that helps, but seems like it might.

Comment: LOL, this is what i was suggesting, hehe

Comment: I didn't see your comment. I was typing at the same time.